# Slider doesn't autostart in Explorer 11

Tags: slider, internet-explorer-11, jssor, autostart

I have been unable to get this code to work on IE11 - it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, Android Chrome, Opera, just not IE. In IE11, I can actually see the images pile in on top of one another until it reaches the last image, then it just stops. The last image is distorted (as if $FillMode is set to 0). However, while clicking on the image makes no difference, dragging it even the slightest amount triggers it into operation. It's as if the auto-start is ignored, but once nudged, the function works. If I do nothing, it sits on the last image loaded indefinitely.

The head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jssor.slider.js"></script>

<script async>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:700,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2}} ]; 
        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        var startImgNumber =Math.floor((Math.random()*16)+1);
        var options = {
            $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
            $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
            $PlayInMode: 1,
            $PlayOutMode: 3},
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $DragOrientation: 1,            
            $AutoPlayInterval: 5000,  // ADJUST!!!!
            $FillMode: 1,
            $SlideHeight: 260,
            //$PauseOnHover: 0,
            $StartIndex: startImgNumber,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            }
         };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();

        if (parentWidth) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            }
          else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end

    });
</script>
```

HTML code is:

```
<div id="PhotoShow" >

<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px  width: 332px; height: 260px; ">
    <!-- Slides Container -->  

    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 330px; height: 260px; overflow: hidden;">

        <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/pic1.jpg" title="Photo By me &copy;2015" alt=""/><div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 245px; left: 100px; width: 200px;height: 30px; color:#FFFBF0; font-size:x-small" >Courtesy of me &copy; 2015</div></div>

        <div><img data-u="image" src="photos/pic2.jpg" title="Photo By me &copy;2015"alt=""/><div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 245px; left: 125px; width: 200px;height: 30px; color:#ffffff; font-size:x-small"  >me &copy; 2015</div></div>

    .
    .
    .   16 images total

     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

(Possible I have extra /div tags - that is not the issue, just a typo), I am completely at a loss as to why this works on everything except IE11. It appears that the function simply does not execute. I've tried window.onload and a few other things - changes nothing.

Thanks for any clues or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semicolon is missing in your html code.

Please replace

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px  width: 332px; height: 260px; ">
```

with

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;  width: 332px; height: 260px; ">
```

Comment: PERFECT. Sometimes it just takes an extra pair of eyes, must've looked at that code 100 times, and even this morning, it took three mental parses to see it!!! Thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: As a brief follow up - is there a command in jssor slider to randomize the image selection?

Comment: var options = { ..., $StartIndex: yourRandomIndex, ... }

Comment: Thanks ... yes that picks the first slide, but all the others that follow are still in the same order. Thanks though